# Error when function is in a separate C file

Tags: c, linker

I have a file API.c in which there are certain functions but no main function.

Inside one of the functions , I call shmat() and return :

```
        #include<stdio.h>
        #include<stdlib.h>
        #include<sys/shm.h>
        #include<unistd.h>
        #include <sys/types.h>
        #include <sys/ipc.h>
        #include <sys/sem.h>
        #include <sys/msg.h>
        #include <sys/types.h>
        #include <sys/ipc.h>
        #include<string.h>
        #include<fcntl.h>
        #include<errno.h>
        #include<sys/stat.h>
        #include<signal.h>
        int array1[100]; // TO STORE THE SHMIDs
        int array2[100];  // TO STORE THE RSHMIDs
        char * array3[100]; //TO STORE THE SHMAT ADDRESSES


    struct msgbuf
    {
        long type;
        int key;
        int rshmid;
        int size;
        void * addr;
        int cmd;
        int pid;
        int shmid;
    };
    struct msgbuf my,rec;

        int  queue_id; 
        int rshmget(int key,int size)
        {   
            queue_id = msgget(1234, IPC_CREAT |  0666);
            printf("1\n");

            my.type =1;
            my.key=key;
            my.size=size;
            my.pid=getpid();
            //SENDING REQUEST OF CLIENT TO SERVER
            if (msgsnd (queue_id, &(my), sizeof (my), 0) == -1)
            {
            perror("msgsnd");
            }

             //SERVER CREATES SHARED MEMORY AND WRITES THE REPLY BACK
            while(1)
            {
                if (msgrcv (queue_id, &(rec), sizeof (rec), getpid(), IPC_NOWAIT) != -1)
                {
                    printf("GOT MSG\n");
                    break;
                }

                sleep(1);
            }
//ARRAY 1 STORES THE ACTUAL SHMID OF SHARED MEMORY
//ARRAY 2 STORES RSHMID , WHICH IS THE ID RETURNED TO CLIENT
            array1[key%100] = rec.shmid;
            array2[key%100] = rec.rshmid;

            return rec.rshmid;
    }

    void * rshmat(int rshmid, void* addr)
    {

        my.type =2;
        my.rshmid = rshmid;
        my.pid=getpid();
        int i;
// IDENTIFYING THE SHMID CORRESPONDING TO THE RSHMIDS
        for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            if(array2[i]==rshmid)
            break;
        }
//ARRAY 3 STORES THE ADDRESSES CORRESPONDING TO EACH SHMAT
        array3[i] = shmat(array1[i],NULL,0);
  //INFORMING THE SERVER ABOUT THE ATTACHING    
        if (msgsnd (queue_id, &(my), sizeof (my), 0) == -1)
        {
            perror("msgsnd");
        } 
        return array3[i];
    }
```

In the file main.c , i am doing this:

```
 int main()
   {    

        queue_id = msgget(1234, IPC_CREAT |  0666);
        int id1 = rshmget(521,200);

        char * addr1 = (char *)rshmat(id1,NULL);
        strcpy(addr1,"FIRST MESSAGE 123456");
    }
```

When trying to executing the strcpy statement , segmentation fault occurs.

But if I keep the API functions and main in same file, strcpy executes successfully.

According to my understanding, shmat() will return a pointer in heap , so it should be accessible from main.

The fact that it works when code is in the same file might indicate that I am not linking the files properly , but other functions in the  API.c file  are able to return properly.

This is how I am compiling:

```
gcc -c API.c 
gcc -c main.c  
gcc  main.o API.o -o client
```

I am using LINUX operating system.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, it's impossible to answer with only the limited code you show.

Comment: Are you doing a `shmget()` to get the shm_id?

Comment: It will not solve your Segfault problem but `strcpy` is insecure, you should use `strncpy` instead.

Comment: @John `strncpy` have other problems though, like there's being cases leaving the destination string unterminated.

Comment: Since I have no information about the rest of your source code, just wanted to remind you that programs using the POSIX shared memory API must be compiled with cc -lrt to link against the real-time library, librt.

Comment: @AndrewHenle , Yes i did shmget () to get shm_id

Comment: What's the value returned from `shmat()`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, It is a random address/pointer

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have made some changes , please see if it helps

Comment: @jps:  You're not checking for a successful return value.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Are you reffering to the shmat() call ? Since it worked when both main and API were in same file , I thought that it is unnecessary to check in this case

Answer (score 0):

In both files add prototypes for every function that you are using from other file with identifier `extern` in front of them.

e.g. in file `main.c` add `extern void * rshmat(int shm_id);`